# react-native macOS: RCTViewManager callback unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, macos, react-native

I'm doing a bridge with UI component
I need to implement a callback (similar to `onChangeText`, `onKeyUp`, ...)

Getting error `Unrecognized selector sent to instance`
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3afVF.png)

Input.swift

```swift
@objc(RNInput)
class RNInput: RCTViewManager, NSTextFieldDelegate {
  
  @objc var onEnd:RCTBubblingEventBlock?

  ...

}
```

Input.m

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNInput, RCTViewManager)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onEnd, RCTBubblingEventBlock)
@end
```

Input.tsx

```js
const RNInput = requireNativeComponent('RNInput');

export class Input extends React.PureComponent<{}> {

  render() {
    return <RNInput onEnd={(e) => console.log(e)}/>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue,

Implemented additional class:

```swift
class CustomNSTextField: NSTextField {
  @objc var onEnd: RCTDirectEventBlock?
}
```

and Input.swift

```swift
class RNInput: RCTViewManager, NSTextFieldDelegate {
  
  override func view() -> NSView! {    
    return CustomNSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(200,20,200,20));
  }
  
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Denis! This actually worked for me as well, but I'm trying to wrap my head around why it worked? Can you explain your reasoning? Are you setting `RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onEnd, RCTBubblingEventBlock)` in your `Input.m` file, and if yes, why? `onEnd` is not a property of  the `RNInput` anymore. Also, I don;t understand why does `CustomNSTextField` inherit from `NSTextField`? Could it be just an `NSObject`?